# Алгоритм выборки из БД без дублей

Tags: python, алгоритм, хеширование, база-данных

Имеется база данных SQLite3, в ней 2 поля:

1. строка;
2. `crc32` этой строки.

Нужно за минимально короткое время и с минимальными ресурсозатратами найти все уникальные  строки. Количество записей - от 1 млн до 100 млн. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными задачами, буду благодарен за любые варианты. Особенно интересны варианты с использованием побитовых операций над `crc`. Код на python.

P.S. Видел вскользь упоминающийся метод примерно такого принципа: 
берется 32 числа типа int, извлекается crc32 строки, затем побитовым OR и AND каким то образом из этих 32 чисел выясняется, был ли проверен данный crc или нет. Реализация данного алгоритма остается неясной.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, запрос `SELECT DISTINCT string FROM tbl` тут будет не самый оптимальный.

Тогда можно попробовать следующий алгоритм(предварительно необходимо создать индекс по crc32):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

# тут подключение к БД
# cur = ...

def select():
    # чем больше это число, тем больше будет запросов 
    # и тем меньше будет выборка и наоборот, соответственно.
    # к примеру, для числа 13 
    # будет сделано 8191 запросов, по ~12 000 записей (для 100 млн.)
    delimiter = 13
    max = 1 << delimiter
    sql = 'select string, crc32 from tbl where crc32 & %d = %%d' % (max - 1)

    for i in xrange(max):
        # не уверен, что сортировка тут будет эффективнее, чем в sqlite
        yield sorted(cur.execute(sql % i), key=itemgetter(1))

prev_crc32 = None
prev_strings = set()

# chain нужен для того, что бы объединять несколько итераторов в один
for string, crc32 in chain(*select()):
    if crc32 != prev_crc32:
        # новый crc32 - новый набор строк
        prev_crc32 = crc32
        prev_strings.clear()

    if string in prev_strings:
        # дубль - пропускаем
        continue

    # уникальная строка, добавляем в set
    prev_strings.add(string)

    # и обрабатываем (выводим, пишем в файл или еще что)
    print(string)
```

Comment: сори, описка, исправил. нужно найти все уникальные строки

Comment: принцип понятен, но он влечет постоянное наличие всей выборки в памяти - при количествах > 1 млн. - это чревато

Comment: Обновил.

>  он влечет постоянное наличие всей выборки в памяти

Если речь про запрос, то можно добавить limit offset и делать выборки по 10-20 штук. К сожалению, я плохо знаком с SqLite3 и не знаю можно ли там делать не буфферизованную выборку.

Comment: да, действительно, при такой реализации (order by) можно сделать лимиты и вообще ничего не держать в памяти. но сам order by очень нежелателен. выполняется он крайне долго и сильно грузит диск

Comment: Обновил ответ еще раз.

Comment: 8000 запросов пробегающих по 100 млн. записей - интересно, сколько времени это займет ? Для записи длиной 100 байт - сколько байт надо прочесть с диска ?

Comment: Предполагается наличие индекса.

Comment: проблема в том, что установка индекса невозможна по причине уникализации поля - а значит при вставке критически увеличивается нагрузка на диск и время работы. а без индекса приведенный Вами пример будет работать очень медленно. Спасибо большое за ответы - но по всей видимости нужно копать в сторону случайной выборки и уже последующего анализа, без участия бд

Comment: Т.е. добавление в базу критичнее, чем выборка. Ну тогда других вариантов, собственно, нету. Или все-равно придется строить в памяти гигантскую хэш-таблицу, или одно из двух.

Answer (score 0):

Если это у вас случилась авария, а не что-то такое что нужно делать постоянно то я бы посоветовал создать точно такую же таблицу, задать нужные столбцы как уникальные индексы, и потом пройтись INSERT SELECT. Все дубли просто не будут внесены в новую таблицу. Но если это у вас что-то дя постоянного использования то это не совсем хорошая идея поскольку вовремя INSERT SELECT таблица лочится.

Comment: да, это постоянные операции. установка uniq на поле не подходит - при увеличении количества результатов увеличивается нагрузка на диск. желателен какой-либо способ выдергивать строго определенное количество (например, 50 тыс), затем проверять неким способом crc на уникальность, и затем уже записывать в новую бд. Вот способ, которым будет идти проверка на уникальность собственно и интересует

Answer (score 0):

Проверка в программе 50000 crc32 элементарна. (Это на основе Вашего комментария)

Читаете запись из базы, пишите ее в файл, заносите crc вместе с смещением строки в файле в хэш-таблицу в памяти (элемент займет байт двадцать). Если уже есть - значит сверяете со строками в файле и определяете дубликат.

**UPD**

[[@ilya_tt](/users/3179/ilya_tt)](/users/3179/ilya_tt), Этот "ответ" о 50000 crc скорее попытка привлечь внимание к обсуждению серьезного вопроса о поиске в массиве из 100 млн. строк.

Кстати, я так и не понял, Вы планируете далее иметь массив уникальных строк или с дубликатами ? Дальнейшие рассуждения основаны на предположении что Вам нужен массив с дубликатами, но есть запросы об уникальности строки.

Вам ведь нужно искать **уникальные строки**, а у двух разных строк crc может совпадать. При длине строки 100 байт массив данных, который надо просматривать составит 10 GB. Видимо методы его обработки в памяти надо отбросить.

Собственно из всех crc можно построить битовую строку (500 MByte) и держать ее в памяти (если памяти **много** (paging не начнется)). Нулевой бит в ней будет означать, что такого crc нет. Она  строится за один проход по данным и может ускорить алгоритм добавления новых строк (например, если добавляются только уникальные строки). Для проверки уникальна ли строка с таким crc в базе, данный метод бесполезен.

Поэтому мне кажется, что без индекса по всем строкам в этой задаче все равно не обойтись. Если применять СУБД, возможно стоит подумать о выносе индекса на выделенный **SSD**.

Comment: Если правильно понял, то 20*10^8 = 2 гб в памяти. возможно есть какой-нибудь вариант организации хэша с помощью битовых операций?